# How to change theme color of parameter name indicator in Android Studio editor?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I applied a theme for the editor and I didn't like the color of the indicator for the parameter name in Android Studio.

I tried to change it form settings, but I wasn't successful.. Any Help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can change it from File->Setting->Editor->Language Defaults